# Regular Expression to allow specific special characters

Tags: java, regex, validation, special-characters

I'm currently validating a User Name input and I have to validate that certain special characters are allowed to be inserted into the input.

The White List of characters are:

`$#+{}:?.,~@"` and white spaces

And the Black Listed characters are:

`^$;\-()<>|='%_`

The validation should allow any alphanumeric character with one or more special characters and white spaces. It could also work with the black list case either way is fine.

I had this:

```
public static boolean alphNum(String value) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\w ]*[^\\W_][\\w ]*$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
    return m.matches();
}
```

for only alphanumeric characters and white spaces but now the want that specific list of special characters to be allowed also.

Here are some examples of the types I need to allow:

- Name1$
- Name1# Name2
- Name1 Name2
- Name Name2
- Name1 Name...

I've seen a lot of regex validations but none this specific, if anyone could help me out with this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: So, there must be at least one special character, including white space?

Comment: You have $ in both white and black list?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. What is the purpose and difference between white-list and black-list (your example contains `$` which is part of both lists)?

Comment: what about characters that aren't on either list?

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula It's not mandatory to have at least one special character nor white space.

Comment: @Shar1er80 it was a typo sorry, the $ should be allowed

Comment: @hairraisin that's why I got the White List characters, the idea is to be based on allowing only those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no restrictions such as "must start with a letter" or "must contain at least one letter" (your question doesn't specify any), and assuming that by "white spaces" you mean a space, but not tabs, newlines, etc., then the expression would just be:

```
Pattern.compile("^[\\$#\\+{}:\\?\\.,~@\"a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
```

Note that this regular expression allows things such as only a single space, or a user name identical to another one except for the number of trailing spaces, etc. if you want to be a little more restrictive and enforce starting with a letter or number (for example), you could do:

```
Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9][\\$#\\+{}:\\?\\.,~@\"a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
```

Comment: Yes it must have at least 1 alphanumeric character, the special characters isn't a must, and it has no regulation whether it should be at the beginning or the end for either the alphanumeric or the special character

Comment: you're really verifying 2 conditions: 1) there must be at least 1 alphanumeric character, and 2) all characters must be characters in the white list. While it's /possible/ to do this in a single regular expression, I tend to use a separate expression for each condition, for my own sanity. so 2) is checked by the first regex in my answer, 1) could be checked with `Pattern.compile("[0-9a-zA-Z]").matcher(value).matches()`

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern which allows characters that are not on your blacked listed characters.

```
"[^^;\\-()<>|='%_]+"
```

The first `^` means **NOT** any of the following characters.  Until you clarify if the `$` is good or bad, I'm treating it as a good character.

Code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> userNames = new ArrayList() {{
        add("Name1$");          // Good
        add("Name1# Name2");    // Good
        add("Name1 Name2");     // Good
        add("Name Name2");      // Good
        add("Name1 Name");      // Good
        add("UserName$");       // Good
        add("UserName^");       // Bad
        add("UserName;");       // Bad
        add("User-Name");       // Bad
        add("User_Name");       // Bad
    }};
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^^;\\-()<>|='%_]+");

    for (String userName : userNames) {
        if (pattern.matcher(userName).matches()) {
            System.out.println("Good Username");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Bad Username");
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Good Username
Good Username
Good Username
Good Username
Good Username
Good Username
Bad Username
Bad Username
Bad Username
Bad Username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Patteren {
       private static final Pattern specialChars_File = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9-/.,:+\\s]*");

     //CASE-1 : Allow only charaters specifed, here im aloowiing ~ '
      private static final Pattern specialCharsRegex_Name = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9~']*");

      //.CASE-2: Dont Allow specifed charaters, here im not aloowiing < >
      private static final Pattern specialCharRegex_Script = Pattern.compile("[<>]");

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     if (!specialCharsRegex_Name.matcher("Satya~").matches()) {
       System.out.println("InValid....Error message here ");
     }

     if (specialCharRegex_Script.matcher("a").find()) {
       System.out.println("SCript Tag ... Error Message");
     }
   }
 }
```